# Amazon s3 Javascript- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, upload, cors

Am trying to upload my file via:

```
console.log("not broken til here");
    scope.inputMemeIsFile=true;
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'townhall.images'}});
    file = image.file;
    console.log(file);

    var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
      bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        var result = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.';
        console.log(result);
        console.log(err);
      });
```

However, am getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/<BUCKETNAME>/favicon.jpg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

with the proceedingError: `Network Failure {message: "Network Failure", code: "NetworkingError", time: Tue Feb 17 2015 13:37:06 GMT-0500 (EST), region: "us-east-1", hostname: "s3.amazonaws.com"…`}

My CORS config looks like the following and I have tried a couple things with no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Anyone have any idea whats wrong? I've looked at 5-6 similar posts but no one seems to be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> In order to upload files via browser, you should ensure that you have configured CORS for your Amazon S3 bucket and exposed the "ETag" header via the ETag declaration.

I would suggest you start with an open test configuration and then modifying it to your needs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Then check your bucket permissions and your `AWS` configuration (`accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey`, and `region`) since none of these are present in your snippet.

For testing, go to your IAM Management Console and create a new IAM user named `prefix-townhall-test` then create a group with this simple policy that grants access to a bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-name"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-name/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Make sure the user you created is using the new group with this policy.

Now create a simple test script like the one used on amazon this:

**HTML**

```
<input id="file-chooser" type="file" />
<button id="upload-button">Upload</button>
<p id="results"></p>
```

**CODE (on DOM ready)**

```
// update credentials
var credentials = {accessKeyId: 'new accessKeyId', secretAccessKey: 'new secretAccessKey'};
AWS.config.update(credentials);
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-1';

// create bucket instance
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'test-bucket-name'}});

var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
var results = document.getElementById('results');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var file = fileChooser.files[0];
    if (file) {
        results.innerHTML = '';

        var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
        bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
            results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.';
        });
    } else {
        results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Have tried the ETag variation too and the one you stated above, same problem.

Comment: In terms of the config...  <script type="text/javascript">
  // See the Configuring section to configure credentials in the SDK
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '<FIRST_KEY>', secretAccessKey: '<OTHER_KEY>'});
    //AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
  </script>. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In terms of permissions, I have granted everyone access to list, upload/delete, view permissions

Comment: What information would be helpful to help resolve the problem?

Comment: @user3525295 what are the IAM permissions set for the credentials used for your AWS configuration?  Try this simple test.  Make a new IAM user and grant them full access to S3 and use it's `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` for your test.  If you're using US-Standard as your region then leave region out of the AWS config.

Comment: @user3525295 can you tell me the bucket region you are using?

Comment: Theres a chance that this might be right... How do I grant full access to S3 on a user? I did it on my s3 bucket already where I granted permission to everyone. Bucket: townhall.images
Region: Northern California
Creation Date: Mon Feb 16 15:34:50 GMT-500 2015
Owner: Me

Comment: I'm pretty sure if it was an access key problem that would prompt an invalid access key problem as well (which would be an xml output). I've seen it when I tried to use other methods to do this.

Comment: @user3525295 I've updated my answer to give you a small test environment.  It works for me with javascript AWS SDK and allows me to upload just fine.  If you want, I can even  put the example in a fiddle but, will probably delete the user eventually.

Comment: Could you put into a JS fiddle? I just tried and am encountering the same error :(

Comment: @user3525295 your error seems to be stating that the bucket is isn't in `us-east-1`.  Can you make sure the request is going to `us-west` or whichever Northern California is.  Let me make a test bucket in Northern California and test it out.

Comment: It seemed to be a problem with the bucket, i remade antoher one in US Standard and it worked instead of US region

Comment: @user3525295 I just tested in Northern California and it worked fine with `AWS.config.region = 'us-west-1';` and the bucket using the example CORS configuration.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @jungy, ended my 2 day annoyance!

Answer (score 15):

Some browsers, such as Chrome, do not support `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for CORS requests.

Try using instead: `http://lvh.me:5000/`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892392/1464716 for more.

Comment: Just tired, same effect. This was a good suggestion though and one I have not tried, any other suggestions?

Comment: This actually worked for me.  I tried with the suggested CORS header in Safari instead of Chrome and voila.

Comment: This worked for me.  In my search to understand `http://lvh.me`, I discovered `localho.st`, which is more self-documenting in my CORS config.

Answer (score 9):

The current answer is pretty outdated. So here's my sharing:

First you need to setup CORS on your AWS S3 bucket

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://*",
            "https://*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "ETag"
        ],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Just a note on the cors for S3. When applying a policy, files already in the bucket are NOT updated. So make sure you apply a CORS policy to only new buckets, or re-add the content after applying the policy. Old content won't be affected by new CORS policy

How amazon S3 evaluate CORS?

- The request's Origin header must match an AllowedOrigin element.
- The request method (for example, GET or PUT) or the Access-Control-Request-Method header in case of a preflight OPTIONS request must be one of the AllowedMethod elements.
- Every header listed in the request's Access-Control-Request-Headers header on the preflight request must match an AllowedHeader element.

For the last step, You need to clear cache on browser also because browser might cache the previous pre-flight request

Comment: Thanks– this works in 2022. The XML solutions don't.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the settings i looking for a long time

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried specifying your origin instead of using wildcard. I'm pretty sure we had similar problems in the past.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://127.0.0.1:5000</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>`, without protocol.

If it has no effect – you probably have problem on client side.

Comment: I've tried it already. Could you elaborate on how you would solve the client side problem?

Comment: Possibly, your client cached in some way `<MaxAgeSeconds>ZillionSeconds</MaxAgeSeconds>` if you had it in CORSRules section. Even if you delete it after client cached its value, browser do not try to re-read CORS using OPTIONS request until ZillionSeconds period ends.

To ensure OPTIONS request you may a) clear user agent cache, b) for Chrome – open console, then settings and set No cache while console is open.

Comment: I have my javascript console on and the cache is deleted.